# Simplification of the sum of sine waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I have passed a signal through a filter and gotten the following wave, consisting of a DC component and odd harmonics:

$$1 + 2\sin4000πt + \frac23 \sin12000πt + \frac25 \sin20000πt + \frac27 \sin28000πt + \frac29 \sin36000πt.$$

Is there anyway I can simplify this further so I can get it down to the $A\sin2fπt$ ideally?

Comment: No.  Your signal is a [square wave](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html) (or pretty close to it);  if you could put it into that form it would be a sine wave.   Square waves and since waves are not the same signal.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the comment. The signal isnt a square wave as it only has up to the third odd harmonic, in order for it to be a square wave it would have to have up to the 19th harmonic present

Comment: Well, no, it's not exactly square, but as I said it's [pretty close](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+2*sin(4000%CF%80*t)%2B(2%2F3)sin(12000%CF%80*t)%2B(2%2F5)sin(20000%CF%80*t)%2B(2%2F7)sin(28000%CF%80*t)%2B(2%2F9)sin(36000%CF%80*t)+from+t+%3D+0+to+1%2F1000).  And to be a true square wave it would have to have an infinite number of harmonics present, not just up to the 19th.

Comment: How have you decided that the 19th is the magic limit that makes a square wave?

Comment: Thats what it says in the text I am working from? Is this wrong? Ah i see from what Micheal said regarding an infinite number of odd harmonics. Thanks for clearing that up guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to simplify this expression. Your signal is expressed as the sum of six independent functions (six different frequencies), and the expression in the sine and cosine basis is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Your signal couldn't be a sine wave.

[image]

With 12 items in series :
[image]